# Why the page turned on by selenium is different than through a regular browser

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I practice data scraping on tripadvisor and I can't understand why the penultimate item on the list (item 29) has a link from the last item in it. Link to the list: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g60763-New_York_City_New_York.html
[image]
You can see in the picture that inspected element has wrong link. There is no such problem in a regular browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of the website. Because i tried to open this URL in 4 browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Selenium(Chrome) and the element 29 has href of element 30.
But if you click element **29. Royal 35 Steakhouse** it will open a correct [link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60763-d12015308-Reviews-Royal_35_Steakhouse-New_York_City_New_York.html).
It is because the element 29 has **onclick** event that is linked to the **correct link**.

Write in console of your browser:

```
document.getelementsbyclassname("bHGqj Cj b")
```

You will get 37 elements. Inspect element 34 you will see next:

**This is incorrect URL:**

[image: Bad URL]

**This is correct URL:**

[image: correct URL]

As you can see there is  some property **__reactProps** that has correct data. How i said before when you click element 29 it send you to the correct link.
**It works correctly and that is why nobody realizes that there is an error.**

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get into reactProps in python selenium?

Comment: Try to find something to get event on onclick element or try to use Playwright https://playwright.dev/.